# 2 dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would need to store in a javascript variable the following table:

```
Nodeid  parentid   theme            Document

4787814 4787484 Theme1       Document 1
4787824 4787484 Theme2       NULL
4787834 4787824 Theme2.1     Document 1 of theme 2.1
4787834 4787824 Theme2.1     Document 2 of theme 2.1 
4787834 4787824 Theme2.1     Document 3 of theme 2.1
4787844 4787824 Theme2.2     Document 1 of theme 2.2
4787854 4787824 Theme2.2     Document 2 of theme 2.2
```

Is there any jquery or javascript code that could help me storing this table in a similar structure. By the moment i have the following javascript code.

```
var ThemesCollection=
    {
        Themes: {},
        Initialize: function() 
        {
          ThemesCollection.Themes=new Object();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use objects

```
function ThemesCollection(Nodeid, parentid, theme, Document) {
  this.Nodeid = Nodeid;
  this.parentid = parentid;
  this.theme = theme;
  this.Document = Document;
}
```

and then use array of `ThemesCollection` objects (if you retreive it with ajax)

```
function on_success(data) {
   for (row in data) {
     globalThemes.push(new ThemesCollection(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]);
     // or i row is object
     //new ThemesCollection(row['Nodeid'], row['parentid'], row['theme'], row['Document'])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a matrix (array of arrays)?

```
[ [ 4787814, 4787484, "Theme1",       "Document 1" ],
  [ 4787824, 4787484, "Theme2",       null ],
  [ 4787834, 4787824, "Theme2.1",     "Document 1 of theme 2.1" ],
  [ 4787834, 4787824, "Theme2.1",     "Document 2 of theme 2.1" ],
  [ 4787834, 4787824, "Theme2.1",     "Document 3 of theme 2.1" ],
  [ 4787844, 4787824, "Theme2.2",     "Document 1 of theme 2.2" ],
  [ 4787854, 4787824, "Theme2.2",     "Document 2 of theme 2.2" ] ]
```

If `x` is your matrix you just add new items by doing:

> x.push([4787859, 4787824, "Theme X", "Document foobar"])

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Object Notation.

```
var info = [
{
"Nodeid" : 4787814,
"parented" : 4787484,
"theme" : "Theme1",
"Document" : "Document 1"
},
{
"Nodeid" : 4787824,
"parented" : 4787484,
"theme" : "Theme2",
"Document" : "NULL"
}]
```

Then, you can use your two dimensional array like this;

```
alert(info[0].theme)
```